# Best workflow to set-up Azure web-app with multiple developers

Tags: azure

We've recently set-up our resources in our Azure Portal and especially giving rights was a lot of work.
I wonder if we did it correctly and in the proper order. Our web application seems to work fine.

Next week our client wants us to set-up our environment in his account. This time I want to do it properly ;)
What is the best approach to do this? I don't want to bother him everytime I need to change something.

The situation:

- 2 developers. 1 of them (myself) needs to add extra resources.
- 1 resource group
- Web app using the S1 plan
- 4 deployment slots. 2 will be created right away, the other two later
- 1 Storage account
- 1 SQL Server
- 1 Elastic pool
- Several SQL databases. Some will be created by code.

The last time I needed to give my co-worker access to each resources in the project. I assume that can be done eassier.

What role do I need myself to be able to access all resources and create deployment slots, create databases and set-up continuous build?

Comment: This question risks being closed as opinion-based, as you titled it "best workflow" - which is not actually your question. It's a valid question, but still at risk of being closed as off-topic, since it's not for StackOverflow; it's not programming-related. It should be moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the relevant resources are located in the same resource group (which is the recommended pattern), you just need to give Contributor access to the resource group, and it will apply to everything in it.

Comment: Thanks David that is exactly what I did last week (after reading your comment) and it is working. I was asking for the recommended pattern because I couldn't find it. For future reference: I started using my clients account and created a resource group, I added myself and my colleague as Contributor. Next I created a web-app, databases and storage and used the resource group. Now I can log in and see my clients environment.

Comment: Yes, there is probably not enough material out there to provide guidance. But you're doing the right thing :)